# scalar dimension to the approximation of an integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(M,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ space of probability.

If $f\in L^1(\mu)$ then $f=\displaystyle{\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n}\alpha_i\chi_{C_i}$ where $C_i\in \mathcal{A}$ and $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

My question is this: the $\alpha_i$ scalars are necessarily bounded? i.e. there $K>0$ such that $\vert \alpha_i \vert \leq K $ for all $i\geq 1$